# From a encrypted file can i identify algorithm that use to encrypt it

Tags: algorithm, encryption

If i have an encrypted files is there any methodology to determine what is the algorithm that is used to encrypt that file. So that i can decrypt it. Is there any unique pattern that algorithms use while it encrypts? Please be kind enough to help me out. Thank you.

Comment: How do you know the key if you don't even know the encryption method? I would suggest you to try the `file` Unix utility, it knows quite a lot about file types

Answer (score 2):

The output from any good encryption algorithm is indistinguishable from truly random data. Hence there is no way to determine the algorithm itself.

Comment: While that's true, the OP is asking about *files*. It makes sense to prepend the encrypted file with some meta information like the exact algorithm in use, because the content is secret anyways (unless you need plausible deniability, but having a random file is also not very plausible)

Comment: Also indistinguishability means something different than you claim it does: The cipher text *does* have to be indistinguishable from cipher text of a known message, but not from random data. For example, if you modify AES-CBC so that it inserts a zero byte between every two adjacent output bytes, you still have indistinguishability

Comment: @NiklasB. Although *some* encryption tools store metadata, not all do. In the general case, you can't count on such data being there.

Comment: @JimMischel: I didn't say that. Still it's wrong to say that encrypted files are "indistinguishable" from random files